# Node coloring by taxonomy

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms

My site has a node and a "tags" taxonomy that contain the color field. One node can have multiple tags, but I need to select one main tag. The color from the main tag must be passed to the node. How do I implement it?

Comment: There are thousand ways to implement this. Most basic probably is that the tags have a color field with a select list to select predefined colors and each value represents a CSS class. In the node load the term, load it's color value and put that as a class like `<article class="color-{{ my_color }}>`.

Comment: One node can have 3-4 terms, but I need to somehow choose the main one from which the color will be taken. My problem is that there can be multiple terms.
I was thinking about making two taxonomy references, but that's not a good idea because the main term will be duplicated in both fields

Comment: Make a single value taxonomy reference field to it, then you'll know what color to use. It's not duplication, it's just a second reference.

Comment: You could - by convention - declare the first value as the main value. In the field settings, in the "help text" field, document that convention for your editors.